# Arch: libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable

Tags: arch-linux, video, nvidia, 64bit, 32bit

I've a problem with certain 32 bit game on 64 bit Arch Linux.

It looks like the problem lies in my 32 bit enviroment which cannot see my 64 bit NVidia drivers.

When I launch 64bit version of `glxgears` it works smoothly and there are no errors in console. 32 bit version is not smooth and console says:

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears32
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/xorg/modules/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/xorg/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/michal/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/michal/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I was trying to google this problem but there are usually tips for Ubuntu which doesn't seem to be applyable on Arch.

I've installed some 32 bit libs:
lib32-nvidia-utils, lib32-opencl-nvidia, lib32-mesa-libgl which seemed for me to be the missing ones (basing on Ubuntu's forums) but they didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing: lib32-nvidia-libgl and lib32-mesa-libgl was bad choice ;)

Comment: When you can, make sure to mark this as the correct answer :)

Comment: @Joe: here you go :)